# How do I display data from a get request to show within an option tag?

Tags: arrays, json, angular, typescript

I have a get request that retrieves data from a REST API. Below is the response.

```
{
    "listCustomFields": [
        {
            "configurationType": null,
            "errorDetails": null,
            "fieldId": "312329",
            "listItems": [
                "Banking Services",
                "Business Banking",
                "Commercial",
                "Consumer Lending"
            ],
            "name": "Department Name",
            "required": "true",
            "show": "true",
            "value": null
        },
        {
            "configurationType": null,
            "errorDetails": null,
            "fieldId": "373914",
            "listItems": [
                "BB Account Servicing - Add/delete signer",
                "BB Account Servicing - Online Banking for Business - Add Business Account Form",
                "BB Lending - Express Business Credit Application"
            ],
            "name": "Documents being sent",
            "required": "false",
            "show": "true",
            "value": null
        }
    ],
    "textCustomFields": [
        {
            "configurationType": null,
            "errorDetails": null,
            "fieldId": "355485",
            "name": "Account Number",
            "required": "true",
            "show": "true",
            "value": null
        },
        {
            "configurationType": null,
            "errorDetails": null,
            "fieldId": "418149",
            "name": "Obligor Number",
            "required": "false",
            "show": "true",
            "value": null
        },
        {
            "configurationType": null,
            "errorDetails": null,
            "fieldId": "418150",
            "name": "Business Name",
            "required": "false",
            "show": "true",
            "value": null
        },
        {
            "configurationType": null,
            "errorDetails": null,
            "fieldId": "418151",
            "name": "System of Record",
            "required": "false",
            "show": "true",
            "value": null
        },
        {
            "configurationType": null,
            "errorDetails": null,
            "fieldId": "418152",
            "name": "SSN",
            "required": "false",
            "show": "true",
            "value": null
        },
        {
            "configurationType": null,
            "errorDetails": null,
            "fieldId": "433716",
            "name": "Document Type",
            "required": "false",
            "show": "false",
            "value": null
        },
        {
            "configurationType": null,
            "errorDetails": null,
            "fieldId": "433717",
            "name": "Document Category",
            "required": "false",
            "show": "false",
            "value": null
        },
        {
            "configurationType": null,
            "errorDetails": null,
            "fieldId": "433718",
            "name": "Documsnt Sub-Category",
            "required": "false",
            "show": "false",
            "value": null
        }
    ]
}
```

When trying to display the listItems object within the listCustomFields Array, in an option tag the whole list is on one line.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVDpf.jpg)

Here is my call to the API

`getCustomFields(): Observable<any> {     return this.http.get(this.apiUrl);   }`

Here is my method

`getCustomField(){     this.customFieldService.getCustomFields().subscribe((res) => {       this.data = res;       console.log(this.data);     });   }`

And here is my HTML

```
                        <select id="dropdown" name="listCustomFields" class="form-select" formControlName="listCustomFields" >
              <option *ngFor="let d of data.listCustomFields; let index = index;"><ng-container  *ngIf="index===0">{{ d.listItems }}</ng-container>
              </option>
            </select>
```

I'm not sure what i am missing.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first please consider using `pipe` + `catchError` + `throwError`  after your get request. More over please dissociate successfull and unsuccessfull response in your subscribe with `next` and `error` and/or 'complete` see https://rxjs.dev/deprecations/subscribe-arguments.

And here update version from James code removing the useless index

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let d of data.listCustomFields">
     <option *ngFor="let x of d.listItems">{{x}}</option>
</ng-container>
```

Never declare useless variables.
Have a good day ! ╰(*°▽°*)╯

Comment: Thank you for your help, sorry for the delay response.

Comment: @harsh-mangalam Now that all the options are displaying in the UI when I select more than one option only one appears in my json.  How do I get so that all options I select show in my json?  Thanks

Comment: in your template : `(ngModelChange)="onSelectItem($event)"` and in your component onSelectItem(newItem : Item ) { if ( !itemList.includes(Item) itemList.push(newItem); } please note this is an exemple but I hope this will help u. The includes is for avoiding duplicates in your list ;D

Answer (score 1):

I don't have much time to give a more in-depth answer, but you have to consider that 'listItems' is an array. In order to access any singular array item, you need an index so 'd.listItems[0]' would be "Banking Services". 'd.listItems' would reference the whole array, which is probably why it shows all the entries.

I recommend another *ngFor(let x of listItems) and you can use {{x}} as one of the entries.

Also, I think your use of ng-container is a little odd. Here is how I may write this snippet:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let d of data.listCustomFields; let index = index;">
     <option *ngFor="let x of d.listItems">{{x}}</option>
</ng-container>
```